# React js to add panel event issue

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Im beginner for the **reactjs**, I added some panel for my react project, i faced some conflict on that button event, when the click on button panel not open,
anyone know how to correctly add this

That is my code.
**index.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import Hello from './Hello';
import './style.css';

class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      name: 'React'
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
       <div id="mySidepanel" class="sidepanel">
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">×</a>
        <a href="#">About</a>
        <a href="#">Services</a>
        <a href="#">Clients</a>
        <a href="#">Contact</a>
      </div>
      <button class="openbtn" onclick="openNav()">☰ Toggle Sidepanel</button>
     </div>

    );
  }
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

**hello.js**

```
import React from 'react';

export default ({ name }) => <h1>Hello {name}!</h1>;
function openNav() {
  document.getElementById("mySidepanel").style.width = "250px";
}

function closeNav() {
  document.getElementById("mySidepanel").style.width = "0";
}
```

[**stack blitz here**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-jsfd2j)

Comment: You could try [this](https://react-wkbnse.stackblitz.io)

Comment: @PRK Thanks for your guidance , please keep the post answer section, i can vote it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In react, you generally don't modify DOM elements directly, but just render them in the form you currently want them. Your `render` function will be called again any time the state or properties of the component change. (Additionally in react you use `className=` instead of `class=`, and `onClick={function}` instead of `onclick="code"`).

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import Hello from './Hello';
import './style.css';

class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      name: 'React',
      sidepanelOpen: false,
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
       <div id="mySidepanel" className="sidepanel" style={{width: this.state.sidepanelOpen ? '250px' : '0px'}}>
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" className="closebtn" onClick={() => this.setState({sidepanelOpen: false })}>×</a>
        <a href="#">About</a>
        <a href="#">Services</a>
        <a href="#">Clients</a>
        <a href="#">Contact</a>
      </div>
      <button className="openbtn" onClick={() => this.setState({sidepanelOpen: true})}>☰ Toggle Sidepanel</button>
     </div>

    );
  }
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Comment: Sir, Thanks for your valuable guidance

Answer (score 1):

Handling events with React elements is very similar to handling events on DOM elements. There are some syntactic differences:
For example, in HTML:

```
<button onclick="activateLasers()">
  Button
</button>
```

for react :

```
<button onClick={activateLasers}>
  Activate Lasers
</button>
```

in your case :
for opening sidepanel

```
 <button class="openbtn" onClick={this.openNav}>☰ Toggle Sidepanel</button>
```

for closing sidepanel

```
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onClick={this.closeNav}>×</a>
```

and put the function inside the same component

final code looks like this :

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      name: 'React'
    };
  }
  openNav = () => {
    document.getElementById("mySidepanel").style.width = "250px";
  }
 closeNav = () => {
  document.getElementById("mySidepanel").style.width = "0";
}
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
       <div id="mySidepanel" class="sidepanel">
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onClick={this.closeNav}>×</a>
        <a href="#">About</a>
        <a href="#">Services</a>
        <a href="#">Clients</a>
        <a href="#">Contact</a>
      </div>
      <button class="openbtn" onClick={this.openNav}>☰ Toggle Sidepanel</button>
     </div>
    );
  }
}
```